# Wear app does not sync when using Fitness API

Tags: android

I'm creating a watch face and I want to display the steps recorded by the watch (without those from phone).

In order to have access to Fitness API I add

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:8.1.0'
```

To wear gradle dependencies. The problem is that after that the watch face/app does no sync to watch after installed on phone.

Any idea why?

Comment: Anyone willing to test? I cannot get this working ;/ or is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like adding Fitness dependencies forces two permissions **which are not visible in wear AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

After adding those to mobile AndroidManifest.xml now it works.